# How can service worker get the remote ip address of a request?

Tags: javascript

How can service worker get the remote ip address of a request?

[image: devtools screenshot]

Comment: By "remote", you mean the server's one?

Comment: yes,i want to get the server's ip of a request in user's browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123097/1543596) answer.

You have many services you can call and get your IP as response.

One example:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.ip);
}, "jsonp");
```

Comment: But i want to know the ip of specific domain when the users request this domain in their browsers

Comment: You search a dns server?